# Perl decimal to binary conversion

Tags: perl, printf

I need to convert a number from decimal to binary in Perl where my constraint is that the binary number width is set by a variable:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i<32; $i++)
{
    sprintf("%b",$i) # This will give me a binary number whose width is not fixed
    sprintf("%5b",$i) # This will give me binary number of width 5

    # Here is what I need:
    sprintf (%b"$MY_GENERIC_WIDTH"b, $i)
}
```

I can probably use a work-around in my print statements, but the code would be much cleaner if I can do the aforementioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question amounts to the following:

> *How do I build the string `%5b` where `5` is variable?*

Using concatenation.

```
"%".$width."b"
```

That can also be written as

```
"%${width}b"
```

In more complex cases, you might want to use the following, but it's overkill here.

```
join('', "%", $width, "b")
```

Note that `sprintf` accepts a `*` as a placeholder for a value to be provided in a variable.

```
sprintf("%*b", $width, $num)
```

If you want leading zeroes instead of leading spaces, just add a `0` immediately after the `%`.

Comment: my $bin = sprintf("%0${width}b",$i);    Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 7):

You can interpolate the width into the format string:

```
my $width = 5;

for my $i (0..31) {
    printf "%${width}b\n", $i;
}
```

Or use a `*` to input it via a variable:

```
my $width = 5;

for my $i (0..31) {
    printf "%*b\n", $width, $i;
}
```

Both outputs:

```
    0
    1
   10
   11
  100
  101
  110
  111
 1000
 1001
 1010
 1011
 1100
 1101
 1110
 1111
10000
10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

Comment: my $bin = sprintf("%0${width}b",$i);
This completes my problem